# Opening Access report via .net working, but not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am trying to open an access report through .net. I can open it in normal mode using Access.AcView.acViewNormal, but it's not what I want to do because that prompts the user to save the first and then it can be viewed. I want the report to pop up and it seems .acViewPreview or .acViewReport is what i should use, but it's not popping up.

It does open up a process and seems to be opening, but i can't see the report. Perhaps it's closing really fast. The following is the code I have currently

```
private void buttonResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application oAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\\path.mdb",true);

        try
        {
            oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport("rptChartData", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewPreview);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Dot Net.  I put this code in an Excel module and it created an Access instance and displayed my report.  The key seemed to be `oAccess.Visible = True`  Without setting Visible = True, Access opened (and remained open) with the report but was just not visible.

```
Dim strDbFullPath As String
Dim oAccess As Access.Application

strDbFullPath = "C:\Access\webforums\whiteboard2003.mdb"
Set oAccess = New Access.Application

oAccess.Visible = True
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbFullPath, True
oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFoo", acViewPreview
```

So I think this may not be a Dot Net issue, but standard behavior for an Access application instance.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Is there a way to pass variables to that report? It's looking for form values, but instead of having the user type them in, I'd like to automate that. Is it possible? thanks again.

Comment: Ok, i will open up another question.

Comment: ACtually, i figured it out. Thanks again HansUp